# how to read md file in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

i have file as : _nearby/2022-10-03-ancient-places.md
and this file contains as below:

```
---
layout: nearby
title: Ancient places
seo_description: As we live between Chitrakoot and Kaushambi, there are numerous
  ancient locations here.
date: 2022-10-03T04:56:39.531Z
image: /assets/uploads/chitrakoot_0.jpg
categories:
  - Ancient places
nearbyplaces:
  - title: Rishiyan ashram
    description: प्राकृतिक सौन्दर्य से ओत-प्रोत आश्रम जिसे वर्तमान में ऋषियन आश्रम
      के नाम से जानते हैं,यह उत्तर प्रदेश की धर्मनगरी के नाम से विख्यात्
      चित्रकूट के मऊ तहसील से 14 किमी. की दूरी पर बरहा कोटरा गांव में स्थित है।
      वास्तव में इस आश्रम का नामऋषियननहीं था। एक किवदन्ति के अनुसार, ‘बरहा’ गांव
      के जंगल में 84000 ऋषियों ने तपस्या की थी जिससे इस स्थान का नाम पहले
      ‘‘ऋषिवन’’ पड़ा तथा बाद में यह अपभ्रंस होकर ‘‘ऋषियन आश्रम’’ हो गया।
    entry_fee: Free
    timings: 10 AM - 6PM
    best_time: Always
    link: ""
    map: https://goo.gl/maps/WDn1hp3BknuXiTSM8
    image: /assets/uploads/2022-06-29.jpg
  - title: Alha Ghat
    description: Alha Ghat
    image: /assets/uploads/2022-08-17.jpg
    entry_fee: 20 Rupee
    timings: 10AM - 5PM
    best_time: Rainy and Winters
    map: https://goo.gl/maps/715vnrMg9x958De47
---
As we live between Chitrakoot and Kaushambi, there are numerous ancient locations here.
```

i am want to read variable from this file and want to use in any page.

my try:

```
my_variable: nearby/2022-10-03-ancient-places.md
{% my_variable.image %}
```

but its showing error

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/ for a reference to all variables available in Jekyll:

> **Page**: Page specific information + the front matter. Custom variables set via the front matter will be available here.

Use `{{ page.image }}` to show the image URL but use `![alt text]({{ page.image }})` to show the image.

See https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/ for markdown syntax examples.